# When will the next LTS version of Ubuntu be released?

Tags: release-management

I am a bit confused about the release schedule of Ubuntu. AFAIK, it releases a new version every 6 months right? How about the LTS version?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A new Long Term Support (LTS) version is usually released every two years. The current LTS version is **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS** (code name *"Lucid Lynx"*), which was released during April 2010.  Thus the next LTS is road-mapped to be **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** (*code name not yet known*), with a release date expected on [26 April 2012](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PReleaseSchedule).

With the Long Term Support (LTS) version you get 3 years support for Ubuntu Desktop, and 5 years support for Ubuntu Server.

See the [`wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) article for more information.

Comment: A bit more precisely, every fourth release is an LTS.

Comment: @MickTaiwan: done :-

Comment: @jo-erlend: True.

Answer (score 9):

This should answer this question for the next few years:

Pattern - April of every even-numbered year (Every four versions)

14.04

16.04

18.04

20.04

22.04

24.04

*FUN FACT* - Dapper Drake is the only exception (Ubuntu 6.0**6**)

Comment: @AvinashRaj +1 for +1ing me ;)

Comment: @AvinashRaj I know. I +1 your comment stating you +1 my answer.

Answer (score 5):

10.04 was the last one, so the next one will be 12.04, which means it will be released April 2012.

Answer (score 4):

The next LTS release will be in April 2014: 14.04. It will be supported until somewhere in 2019.

More details can be found on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS. Here is an overview of that page. It is hard to see on the image but there is a difference between the desktop and the server version, but that only was for 10:04 (and earlier versions). These days:

> A new LTS version is released every 2 years. In previous releases, a Long Term Support (LTS) version had 3 years support on Ubuntu (Desktop) and 5 years on Ubuntu Server. Starting with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, both versions will receive 5 years support.

[image: Ubuntu release cycle]