# Are LTS releases close to being expired?

Tags: 14.04, lts

I've been considering upgrading my system from 14.04, but have been reading that LTS releases are probably the best for the long run. That being said I noticed that Ubuntu 14.04 will be discontinued after April 2019.

At this point there do not seem to be any other Ubuntu releases with dates beyond April 2019 so my question is  what will be the next LTS release from Ubuntu?  Or... which release will be maintained the longest?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: Wait for it....wait for it....https://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/891689-ubuntu-1604-something-to-get-excited-about

Comment: a google search would have answered your question...

Comment: Nothing personal but I am pretty sure it is written somewhere in the how to stack overflow that you should have been trying to find an information before asking about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual Ubuntu documentation spots haven't been updated yet, but it is expected that [16.04](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus) will be an LTS release, and that it will be supported until 2021. As can be seen on [the Ubuntu wiki page on LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS):

> A new LTS version is released every 2 years. In previous releases, a
>   Long Term Support (LTS) version had 3 years support on Ubuntu
>   (Desktop) and 5 years on Ubuntu Server. Starting with Ubuntu 12.04
>   LTS, both versions will receive 5 years support. There is no extra fee
>   for the LTS version; we make our very best work available to everyone
>   on the same free terms. Upgrades to new versions of Ubuntu are and
>   always will be free of charge.

The graph there was last [updated before](https://askubuntu.com/a/409232/158442) the current latest LTS version was released.