# When does the new LTS will be out?

Tags: upgrade, lts

I'm new to Ubuntu and linux in general... I want to know when does the new LTS version will be out
I'm currently usin Ubuntu 19.04 (non lts) and I want to know if I can upgrade to an LTS version? or I'm stucked with non LTS versions?

Comment: its right in the name, 20.04 ( April, 2020 ).
Is there any particular reason you're using the non-lts 19.04 rather than the more stable and better 18.04 LTS ?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 will release-upgrade to 19.10 (due 2019-October; *yy.mm* format of Ubuntu releases), then to 20.04.  LTS releases can stay LTS (ie. remain 20.04 LTS until 22.04.1 is released) or continue on the non-LTS path.  *fyi:  When 19.10 is released, the release-notes will include instructions for upgrading, eg. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes contained an Upgrading from Ubuntu 18.10 section*

Comment: Ubuntu version numbers are matched with their release date, the next lts version is 20.04 which stands for it's coming out in April(04) of 2020.

Comment: where in the name? well I'm just downloading 19.04 but I thought it would be better beacuse it had improved features... but since you say 18.04 LTS is better i'll download that one... in what part it says that the new LTS will be launched on 2020?

Comment: in the 20.04 part.

20 -> 2020,
04 -> April (the 4th month)

Comment: oh ok thanks I'm really new to this so thanks for the patience... anyway I suppose that with the upgrade manager it will be easy to upgrade it when it comes out.. thank you

Comment: no problem. and welcome to the community.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When will the next LTS version of Ubuntu be released?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51538/when-will-the-next-lts-version-of-ubuntu-be-released) and [What's the difference between a Long Term Support Release and a Normal Release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16366/whats-the-difference-between-a-long-term-support-release-and-a-normal-release)

Answer (score 2):

On the page [The Ubuntu lifecycle and release cadence](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) is provided information that gives exact answer of this question:

> LTS or ‘Long Term Support’ releases are published every two years in
>   April....
>
> [image]

Once a new release is launched, the Software Updater will ask you to update to that new release.

Comment: LTS releases get prompt to upgrade to next release after first point release, i.e. 18.04 users will be notified when 20.04.1 is released which probably release in July